# In Illustrator, how do I set my file at 10% scale?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, scale

I have a large print job. The design is sized at 36" by 72" with 1" bleed. The printer is asking that I set the file at 10% scale. How do I do that???

Comment: Illustrator does not provide a direct method to "*work at scale*" if that is what you are seeking.

Comment: As a person in the print industry, find a new printer. They shouldn't have to ask you to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple to do:

1. Open the Transform palette
2. Lock the width and height
3. In the W: input add "/10" (after the current value in the box in mm/inches/etc).

This will divide the value by 10 and will therefore downscale everything to 10% of its original size.

Comment: you're welcome ) inputs in transform panel accept some math operations and it is really handy..

Comment: I will add to this comment that it's incredibly useful to know you can do basic math in the width and height values (and a few others). Resist the temptation to do the math in other software or on paper and try it in illustrator instead.

Comment: As a shortcut, instead of toggling the width and height lock, you can simply hold CTRL (or Command) down when you hit "enter" and the transform will happen proportionately.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

Resize your artwork:

- (With everything selected) go to `Object > Transform > Scale`
- In the `Uniform` box, enter 10%
- Ensure that everything under `Options` is checked
- Click `OK`

Then resize your `Artboard`:

- (With everything still selected) go to `Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds`

**Method 2:**

Create a new document with your desired dimensions (10% of your current ones) and copy the artwork to that one, scaling it down to fit.

Comment: Good suggestions, however a lot more work is involved for multiple artboards.