# Large-format printing Adobe Illustrator files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have an Adobe Illustrator file that I wish to print; I want to print it on a 60x60in (inches) paper.

My question is: should the Illustrator file also be 60x60in wide? Or it is ok if the dimensions of the document is much smaller and I export the file to PDF and print it big anyway?

Comment: You can do both, working 1:1 scale or work at a smaller size and scale up when exporting. See similar questions [Do I have to create vector files at the correct print size?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36626/do-i-have-to-create-vector-files-at-the-correct-print-size) and [In Illustrator, how do I set my file at 10% scale?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33405/in-illustrator-how-do-i-set-my-file-at-10-scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every element of your graphic is a vector image created in Illustrator, you can create it at any size. That's the beauty of vector graphics. However, if you place a bitmapped image into your Illustrator file, you should create your file at the size that it will be printed - in your case, 60"x60". Regardless of how you output your file, a placed bitmap will not also be scalable.